# why chrome remote webapp build process stuck?

Tags: ninja

I want to build chrome remote desktop web app using chrome remote desktop codes. I have fetch from repository now want to build the chrome remote webapp. I tried the following command from 4 hour but it stuck and have no resposnce. After 4 hour it print the logs like

> ninja -C out/Release/ remoting_webapp
>
> log: ninja version 0.1.3 initializing
>      log: magic group: gid=0 (root)
>      log: entering main Loop
>      log: generating initial pid array..
>      log: now monitoring process activity
>      log: NEW ROOT PROCESS: avahi-autoipd[14897] ppid=14896 uid=0 gid=0
>      log:   - ppid uid=105(avahi-autoipd) gid=113 ppid=1
>      log:   + avahi-autoipd is in magic group, all OK!
>      log: NEW ROOT PROCESS: avahi-autoipd[14944] ppid=14943 uid=0 gid=0
>      log:   - ppid uid=105(avahi-autoipd) gid=113 ppid=1
>      log:   + avahi-autoipd is in magic group, all OK!

Here its stuck and not proceed further. How much time it will take? Is there any error?

Is there is any one can help me?